# Are vectors in integral infinitesimals?

Tags: electric-fields, coulombs-law

There are many equations that deal with the integral, like Gauss' Law and Coloumb's Law. For example, to find the electric field from a continuous distribution requires integrating $d\overrightarrow E = k \frac {dQ}{r^2}\hat r$.

---

In these situations, it is common to see things like $dQ$ is an infinitesimal of the total charge. However, I've read posts like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio) where the first answer states that $dy$ and $dx$ are not infinitesimals because that brings in many problems, with the answerer specifically citing the Archimedian property.  So is technically correct to use the word infinitesimal for $dQ$ for the equation given or for others, or is it just a concept to use in the integral?

Comment: Good enough for physics. Let the mathematicians worry about technicalities. http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2675#comic

Comment: see the Stieltjes integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Answer (score 1):

In physics, we think of them as ratios. They work like ratios algebraically in that you can divide them and cancel them out.

The Archemedian property thing is not really relevant because we are not saying they are real numbers, just that "$d\vec{E}$ is a symbol for an arbitrarily small change in $\vec{E}$, and $\frac{d\vec{E}(t)}{dt}$ is the symbol for the slope (really tangent vector) of the curve which describes how $\vec{E}$ behaves as $t$ varies."